# No Module name 'scrapy.Spider' found

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

Try to excute the code below and using the latest version of scrapy. Don't know what happen

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.Spider import Basespider 


class crawler (Basespider):
  name = "crawler"
  allowed_domains = ['google.com']
  start_urls = ["https://www.google.com"]
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BaseSpide is from scrapy 0.16.5. If you have the newest version, then use another spider. This one is obsolete.